# Find Interpretation for predicate logical formula

Tags: predicate-logic

I Have to find a Interpretation so that $\Im (\alpha)$ is true. But how can i do that?

$$
\alpha1 = \forall x \exists y \exists z (S(x,b) \to Q(x,y,z) \land \forall v (R(v,y) \to T(v,y))), \omega = \mathbb N
$$

for $\alpha1$ as a hint is give: "Each natural number n ≥ 2 has at least one prime factor."

$$
\alpha2 = \forall x \forall y \forall z (S(z) \to ((S(x) \land S(y)) \lor \lnot T(x,y,z))) ,\omega = \mathbb R
$$

for $\alpha2$ as a hint is give: "The addition of a rational and an irrational number yields an irrational number."

Comment: $∀xS(x,b)$ will translate the part : "each number $x \ge 2$". Thus the individual constant $b$ must be interpreted as $2$ and the binary predicate $S(x,y)$ as $(x \ge y)$. And so on...

Comment: But i have to find Interpretations for S,Q,R and T for $\alpha1$ didnt i? But what are Q, R and T for?

Comment: Yes; as said you have to go on with the hint...

Comment: $∃y∃zQ(x,y,z)$ must mean that $y$ and $z$ are factors of $x$ i.e. that $x=y \cdot z$.

Comment: The final subformula must express the fact that $y$ is *prime*.